# Updating list view item values after changing the selected item in a gridview

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listview, gridview

[image]Hello everyone! I am struggling with an issue.

I am developing a windows forms application to calculate the times for people in the company that travels. This is to help HR department.

People fill in a form providing data about the travel and the application will automatically calculate all the times for all the days that people are working abroad.

People from HR department can then consult that in another form and check the values.

I have one form and a grid view (on top, check the pic) and a list view (in the bottom, check the pi) and also some text boxes (in the middle).

What I would like to was to select an item in the gridview and see the values change for the list view and also the text boxes in the same form.
This way we could validate if the app is calculating the times right or not.

Is there anyway to do it?

All help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you aware of [GridView.SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)  Do you need to know more than that?  Not sure what you do or do not know how to do.

Comment: Yes, I finally got it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the [GridView.SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event to be notified when the GridView selection is changed.  In your handler you can update your form accordingly based on the new selection.